# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context: .UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification

Tags: ios, swift

I am getting

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

on the following lines:

```
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willResignActive), name: .UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification , object: nil)
 NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(openedAgain), name: .UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

remove the `.` on `UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification`.

Your line should look like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(willResignActive), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification , object: nil)
```